# Wine System Tray inside Wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

I've made a port of awesome Windows application to make fast translations of text ([QTranslate](https://gist.github.com/wyhasany/d89490272d6a1a5b2cb64b1e6a2d3bf7)). Unfortunately that application uses system tray. After start of that application I see that awfully window. Do you have any idea how to move that small icon into Wingpanel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answers it even if it is a "Won't fix":

> Wine uses an ancient system tray that is not supported.
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1221158

Comment: I am looking a way to put it inside wingpanel

Comment: It appears it is not possible and is something that will not be fixed. It is a minor thing you will just have to deal with.